# How to make Gmail obey `X-SES-Spam-Verdict`

Tags: gmail

I recently transferred a domain to AWS SES and now most users are getting spam in their inbox (false negatives), even though SES spam filtering correctly flags all such spam with the header `X-SES-Spam-Verdict: FAILURE`.

All users are using Gmail, myself included - but I can not find a way to create a Gmail filter that could match headers.

Alternate solution would be to make SES forward the mail to `username+SPAM@gmail.com`, but I'd rather not start hacking the [lambda script](https://github.com/arithmetric/aws-lambda-ses-forwarder)

Comment: Do you mean that you want that the email from the domain that you transferred not be marked as Spam? Did you already try a filter with `from:example.com` (replace example.com with your domain)?

Comment: No, I want the e-mails *TO* that domain that fail the SES spam check to be marked as spam.

Comment: Are you using the email service from AWS SES? Are you using Gmail as an email client for email accounts from that service?